# In Javascript open blank window with a name

Tags: javascript, session-storage

Open a Preview URL in a NEW Window and save the window name in  a session.
So far I have not see any way of specifying the window name and open it  blank

**Without Window Name I cannot save it in Session**

```
 window = window.open(previewUrl, '_blank', 
 "location=yes,height=800,width=1024,scrollbars=yes,status=yes")
```

Is it possible to set the window name later?

**With Window Name does not open in a New Window**

```
  var d = new Date(),m = d.getTime();
  window = window.open(previewUrl, m, 
 "location=yes,height=800,width=1024,scrollbars=yes,status=yes")
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {  
       sessionStorage.previewWindow = m;
  } else {
      console.log('No Sesssion Storage');
  }
```

As  the preview link is not opened onclick of an anchor I cannot set the traget to "_blank"

Answer (score 0):

try to use it on your javascript after your new page load

```
window.name=winName
```

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp) you can see the documentation

But i guess it will be hard to transfer the name to the other window.
so try to use a dinamic name to your new widows

```
window = window.open(previewUrl, myDynamicVar, 
"location=yes,height=800,width=1024,scrollbars=yes,status=yes")
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos, I already create a name "m" . How it is different from myDynamicVar.And does this open in a new window?